# Imagefield Crop – use existing file

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, crop, filefield, imagefield

Is there a way to make a few images with Image Crop out of one uploaded file? Currently i have to upload the same, big pic to get new pics with various dimensions.
Unfortunately the "Imagefield sources"-module doesn´t support Image Crop. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your requirement very well. But if you want multiple versions of the same image it sounds like a use-case for imagcache ( http://drupal.org/project/imagecache )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [imagefield crop](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop) module and you can see this blog for installation and cofiguration [easywebdesigningtutorial.blogspot.in](http://easywebdesigningtutorial.blogspot.in/)